# error CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES while reading back data in host memory while using atomic function in opencl kernel

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am trying to implement atomic functions in my opencl kernel. Multiple threads I am creating are parallely trying to write a single memory location. I want them to perform serial execution on that particular line of code. I have never used an atomic function before.

I found similar problems on many blogs and forums,and I am trying one solution.,i.e. use of two different functions 'acquire' and 'release' for locking and unlocking the semaphore. I have included necessary opencl extensions, which are all surely supported by my device (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 630M).

My kernel execution configuration:

```
global_item_size = 8;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue2, kernel2, 1, NULL, &global_item_size2, &local_item_size2, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Here is my code: reducer.cl

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics : enable

typedef struct data
{
  double dattr[10];
  int d_id;
  int bestCent;
}Data;

typedef struct cent
{
  double cattr[5];
  int c_id;
}Cent;

__global void acquire(__global int* mutex)
{
    int occupied;
    do {
        occupied = atom_xchg(mutex, 1);
    } while (occupied>0);
}

__global void release(__global int* mutex)
{
    atom_xchg(mutex, 0); //the previous value, which is returned, is ignored
}

__kernel void reducer(__global int *keyMobj, __global int *valueMobj,__global Data *dataMobj,__global Cent *centMobj,__global int *countMobj,__global double *sumMobj, __global int *mutex)
{
  __local double sum[2][2];
  __local int cnt[2];

  int i = get_global_id(0);
  int n,j;

  if(i<2)
    cnt[i] = countMobj[i];
  barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

  n = keyMobj[i];
  for(j=0; j<2; j++)
  {
     barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
          acquire(mutex);
             sum[n][j] += dataMobj[i].dattr[j];
      release(mutex);
  }

  if(i<2)
  {
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
       sum[i][j] = sum[i][j]/countMobj[i];
       centMobj[i].cattr[j] = sum[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the solution doesn't seem like working for me. When I am reading back the centMobj into the host memory, using

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue2, centMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, (sizeof(Cent) * 2),  centNode, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue2, sumMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, (sizeof(double) * 2 * 2), sum, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

it is giving me error with error code = -5 (CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES) for both centMobj and sumMobj.

I am not getting if there is any problem in my atomic function code or problem is in reading back data into the host memory. If I am using the atomic function incorrectly, please make me correct.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCL, synchronization between work items can be done *only* inside a work-group. Code trying to synchronize work-items across different work-groups may work in some very specific (and implementation/device dependent) cases, but **will fail** in the general case.

The solution is to either use atomics to serialize accesses to the same memory location (but without blocking any work item), or redesign the code differently.

Comment: You mean to say I can't have synchronization between work-items belonging to the different groups? Even with atomic functions? What if I keep my local_work_size = 1?